# There is a main function in my project but eclipse can't find it

Tags: java

I downloaded a zip from github and import it to eclipse, however, eclipse can't find the main function and I am sure it exists in the project.

I've built the path for it and it didn't work.

```
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
public class XYLineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame
{
 public static void main(String[] args){
        XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT("Browser Usage Statistics", "Which Browser are you using?");
        chart.pack( );
        chart.setLocation(200,200);
        //        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );
        chart.setVisible( true );
    }
}
// there are necessary code and others seem not to be important
```

when i want to run or debug it,eclipse will inform that editor does not contain a main type[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuLPt.png)

Comment: check the launch configuration, is there the correct value? [link](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-3.htm)

Comment: does your eclipse project has a source folder defined ? see Java Build Path in project properties.

Comment: I don't know if you tried but I ran into problems if my cursor wasn't in the editor window. Try to put it there and click again. It might work. Otherwise restart that always helps if you don't want to create the launch config yourself.

Comment: Post a screen of your project view on Eclipse

Comment: Go inside your mail clasd, click the launch icon and select Java Application

Comment: thanks,the second floor got it,the project downloaded didn't have a source folder.

Comment: But when I copy files and paste them under a new source folder created,system add a default source folder under the  new one,how can I solve this problem?